# using Whole and Decimal numbers in a single column in mysql

Tags: mysql, decimal

I'm a music reviewer and I want to build my website. 
I've built a database in mysql with a column for the ratings.
Here are the possibilities : 10, 9.5, 9, 8.5, 8, 7.5 ... 1, 0.5, and 0

What kind of colum can I use, for now I choose DECIMAL with value of : 3,1

The problem is that when I enter 9, it returns 9.0 ... Is there a way to store Whole and Decimal numbers in a column?

Comment: Specialized formatting is best done in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For formatting the numbers for display, you would do that kind of processing in whatever language you were parsing the mysql results in. In PHP, for example, you would simply cast to a float and print it.

```
$string = '9.0000000';
echo (float)$string;
```

This would print '9'.

Answer (score 0):

Store them as a decimal but as a part of 100. 9.9 would be 99. Then use php to divide by 10 and cast it to a double. 
 You can cast to double while dividing by adding a decimal and 0.

Result / 10.0

Comment: Hum, wouldn't be easier to keep it my way and change a 9.0 to a 9 in php after with an if?

Comment: Doubles are far less accurate. Because of how they work your more likely to have issues in the future. With math and comparrisons. If you start doing averages or other comparrisons your likely to run into issues. I would look up how doubles work because they are best avoided when possible just like single precision floats.

Answer (score 0):

You are conflating the value with the representation.  If you are not doing arithmetic on the values (just comparing them), then you might consider storing them as strings.

Alternatively, when selecting them for printing them out, you can format the values as you wish:

```
select (case when rating % 1 = 0 then format(rating, 0)
             else format(rating, 1)
        end)
```

Comment: yes, I only want to compare them, just sorting them, if I store them as strings and I sort them it will go : 0, 0.5, 10, 1, 1.5, 2  ...

Comment: @faf . . . You can always use `order by (rating + 0)`.